# How would I go about having a chat update after loading?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've tried searching on here for a bit to try and find someone with a similar question. I haven't quite yet gotten into implementing the actual retrieval and insertion into the database for the chat messages but I would like to know ahead of time what I'll need to do. You see, on several websites there is updates done to the page after its already been loaded, such as with chat rooms where you're actively given new messages after the page has already loaded. I'm really just posting this as a quick question to see whether this is done through forcing all clients to reload when a new message is posted or what. I would also like to know, if this is done a different way, what language relates to it so I can learn it ahead of time. Thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are various ways you can do it.

One of the more common is to use a websocket server like [Socket.io](https://socket.io/), which maintains a realtime connection between each web client and the server. The realtime server pushes whatever updates you send to the clients.

You can achieve a similar effect using Service Workers and the native browser Push API, as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/IncredibleWeb/Progressive-Web-Chat).

You could also just set an interval timer to ping a server for updates every second, but that is less efficient and performant.